# R- How to merge/bind several dataframes considering that some of the called dataframes might not exist?

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I have to bind/merge dataframes in an iterative process in R. In occasions, some of the dataframes might not exist for reasons I will not explain here. I would like to know how I could bind dataframes even when calling some dataframe that does not exist. As an example, I have these dataframes:

```
df.R_H <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df.B_C <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df.G_H <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))
```

However, in my code I have this:

```
df5 <- rbind(df.R_H,df.B_C,df.G_H,df.R_C)
df5
```

How can I bind dataframes although `df.R_C` does not exist? I can not check individually which dataframes exists or not since I have hundreds of situations like this and I want to do it automatically even when some dataframe does not exist.

Comment: Can you do something like `mget(ls(), envir = globalenv())` to get the dataframes, and then use `rbind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df.R_H <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                     B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                     C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df.B_C <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                     B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                     C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df.G_H <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                     B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                     C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

map_dfr(list("df.R_H","df.B_C","df.G_H","df.R_C"), ~ if (exists(.x)) {get(.x)})

#>    A B C
#> 1  0 3 1
#> 2  4 9 2
#> 3  5 4 4
#> 4  6 5 2
#> 5  7 8 6
#> 6  0 3 1
#> 7  4 9 2
#> 8  5 4 4
#> 9  6 5 2
#> 10 7 8 6
#> 11 0 3 1
#> 12 4 9 2
#> 13 5 4 4
#> 14 6 5 2
#> 15 7 8 6
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mget()` to get `rbind()` all data frames found in the environment. Alternatively for your example you could pass in `x` explicitly to `mget()` as `paste0("df", 1:4)` instead of `ls()`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df2 <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df3 <- data.frame(A=c(0,4,5,6,7),
                  B=c(3,9,4,5,8),
                  C=c(1,2,4,2,6))

df5 <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(), mode = "list", ifnotfound = list(NULL)))
df5
#>       A B C
#> df1.1 0 3 1
#> df1.2 4 9 2
#> df1.3 5 4 4
#> df1.4 6 5 2
#> df1.5 7 8 6
#> df2.1 0 3 1
#> df2.2 4 9 2
#> df2.3 5 4 4
#> df2.4 6 5 2
#> df2.5 7 8 6
#> df3.1 0 3 1
#> df3.2 4 9 2
#> df3.3 5 4 4
#> df3.4 6 5 2
#> df3.5 7 8 6
```

If you have a crowded environment, which is likely, then you can utilize the `pattern` argument of `ls()` to ensure we only pull in relevant data frames through `mget()`. So if all your data frames start with `df...`, then you could use:

```r
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^df*"), mode = "list", ifnotfound = list(NULL)))
```

Comment: Thanks @caldwellst. I obtain the error `Item 5 has 5 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 6 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.`, do you know why?

Comment: If I use `paste0("df", 1:4)`, so I am just curious why `ls()` does not work.

Comment: Just one doubt more. In my real case dataframes are not named with `df1`, `df2`, etc. They have names like `df.H_N`, `df.B_Y`, etc. Does this code work in this situation?

Comment: I have changed the name of the dataframes in the post, since the argument `1:4` does not work in my real case as the dataframes are not differentiated by a number. They all have the same "root.name" (in this example it would be "df."), but then, they are differentiated with different letters that represent differeent things.

Comment: Look at the `pattern` argument of `ls()`, have edited.